# Maven package not outputting .class file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I am using Maven 3.6.3 to compile, build and package my project into **jar**, after running **mvn package** command so there are no *.class* files inside the **jar** all are *.java* files which were generated at the time of compilation so which is not the correct output, what is the correct way to do it?

Below is my folder structure

```
ProjectA
-- src
      com
        hcc
          Folder1
            a.java
            b.java
-- META-INF
      services
        service1.txt
        service2.txt
-- pom.xml
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Utility</groupId>
    <artifactId>UtilityDev</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <base.path>${project.basedir}/../ThirdParty Jars</base.path>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>Utility</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>META-INF</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**services/**</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
            <version>123</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${base.path}/CommonLib/xyz.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't add `src` to the resources.

Instead, put your source code into `src/main/java` and Maven will find it automatically.

Comment: Thanks @JF but we can't put our folder inside like `main/java` as it is a custom structure so is there any other way to do it or tweaking something in pom file.

Comment: First of all "we can't" is not an argument, until at least you have discussed it with your manager. That said, you can set `<sourceDirectory>` in `<build>`  to a different source directory.

Comment: Hey @JF our team is following this custom structure soI have suggested to follow the standard structure but they are not migrating and need to make package from existing project. I have mentioned `src` in `build` but it's not outputting `.class` files.

Comment: So you added `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`?

Comment: Hey @JF just quick question can I set multiple encoding in pom file.

Comment: 1. I don't know what you mean, different encodings for different source code files? That would be horrible. 2. Please, if you have a new question, just ask a new question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211227/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-jf-meier).